# Set date and time in raspberry pi from data in DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS format

Tags: pi-3

I have date and time input by user in the format DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS.
For example: 
27-01-2019 12:47:00 PM IST

Please help me how to set the date, time and time zone of raspberry pi from its command line interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set date & time on Raspberry Pi through a GUI?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93421/how-to-set-date-time-on-raspberry-pi-through-a-gui)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I need to take the date & time input from user in a GUI and set the date/time on raspberry pi without any access to internet. I have the saved the date time info in a text file. But, now the issue is how to set date/time of Pi from that data in the format mentioned above

Comment: Is your code written in Python?

Comment: Yes. Python 3.4.0

Comment: Please edit your question to include additional details, do not post them as comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A programming language agnostic way to do this would be to call the [`date --set="STRING"`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/date) command to set the system clock and then [`hwclock --systohc --utc`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/hwclock) command to set the RTC. How you do this from *your* code depends on the language you use.

From the manual page for `date` it looks like you can drop your string as-is into the command but you might want to check it on the actual version of `date` shipped on your Pi:

> **Date String**
>
> The --date=STRING is a mostly free format human readable
>   date string such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" or "2004-02-29
>   16:21:42" or even "next Thursday". A date string may contain items
>   indicating calendar date, time of day, time zone, day of week,
>   relative time, relative date, and numbers. An empty string indicates
>   the beginning of the day. The date string format is more complex than
>   is easily documented here but is fully described in the info
>   documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `date` utility.

If you really MUST you could build an application around this. Python has date, time and datetime modules.

Frankly you would be better to spend $2 on a RTC module. We used to do things like this in 1975!

Comment: The whole idea is that user enters date and time , which will be stored in the battery backed RTC through Pi's I2C interface. The same RTC will be accessed to get the date and time whenever Pi boots up. Can u explain a bit about ur idea of using Python time modules here?

Comment: @RaghavanK You were the one who raised Python. Setting time in a RTC is a trivial procedure using `hwclock`. You would have been better to have asked your real question rather than posing an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: You have not understood my question. Leave it if you cannot answer. But, u can't make fun of a question just because u think it is simple

Comment: Please calm down and [*be nice*](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Thank you both.